# Magento Extension - Where to store images?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, image, folder

I am coding an extension for Magento 1.9. Now I need an image in my template. Where (which folder) should I store it? And how to access it with an `<img>`-tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the images in the skin folder under the base/default theme.
`skin/frontend/base/default/images/{your_extension_name}/image.png`.
Then access it as:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/{your_extension_name}/image.png')?>" alt="" />
```

If the image is for admin section, then store it in `skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/{your_extension_name}/image.png`